# How to use the template function in the grid using kendoui

Tags: kendo-ui

I am using a template to display some button. I have written the following code :

```
template: kendo.template($("#edit-template").html())
```

And in the edit template I have written :

```
<script id="edit-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <a class="k-grid-edit" style="visibility:hidden;" id="edit">Edit</a>
</script>
```

Initially it will be hidden mode. On databound function, I will show or hide the button. If the permission is shown then I write

```
$(".k-grid-edit").show();
```

Whenever I am updating the grid then the edit button is disappearing again. This is because the button is in hidden state initially. After updating also I need to display that in visible mode. How can i do that.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about transforming your template into:

```
<script id="edit-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    # if (isVisible) { #
        <a class="k-grid-edit">Edit</a>
    # } else {#
        <a class="k-grid-edit" style="display:none">Edit</a>
    # } #
</script>
```

and then have a variable:

```
var isVisible = false;
```

Then toggling it to visible is:

```
isVisible = true;
$(".k-grid-edit").show();
```

while hiding it is:

```
isVisible = false;
$(".k-grid-edit").hide();
```

Basically the variable `isVisible` stores the state and the template checks it using JavaScript.

**NOTE** The template might be more compact but I think this is more readable.

One more question (styling) I removed the `id` from the anchor `a` in your template since `id` must be unique and you were setting the same id for all `kendoGrid` rows.